# How to solve helm error: "did not find expected '-' indicator"?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, helm3

I am trying to deploy a certain node with helm but before I install, I want to ensure the templating is correct hence I am attempting to run `helm template . --debug` and I have an error shown thus:

```
Error: YAML parse error on generic-node/templates/rosetta.yaml: error converting YAML to JSON: yaml: line 39: did not find expected '-' indicator
helm.go:84: [debug] error converting YAML to JSON: yaml: line 39: did not find expected '-' indicator
`
The section with the error is shown thus:
```

```
    - name: ***
      valueFrom:
        secretKeyRef:
          name: "generic-node-devnet-bp-key"
          key: password
    - name: ****
      valueFrom:
        secretKeyRef:
          name: "generic-node-devnet-bp-key"
          key: password
```

And the key for `****` is the line 39, I do not know why it is flagging, could someone help?

Thanks

Comment: That error message can suggest an indentation problem; are you sure everything here has the correct indentation, and that this block is indented at least as much as its containing `env:`?  In a Helm context it's very possible that `{{- ... -}}` whitespace collapsing can hide a crucial newline.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look like you have an issue that lines have too many spaces.  There are YAML checkers on the net, the following link may help you to verify your YAML. http://www.yamllint.com/

Comment: Thank you! This is a live safer